# can't find import: "google.golang.org/cloud/storage"

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I want to work  with the cloud api [gcloud-golang](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang) so i did go get in the **src folder**

```
goapp get google.golang.org/cloud
```

I can "see" the library  in th liteIDE but i cant **goapp serve**

Im getting this exception

```
/home/mik/go-programs/src/google.golang.org/cloud/storage/acl.go:21: can't find import: "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1"

2015/03/14 23:13:37 Can't find package "google.golang.org/api/googleapi" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/googleapi" in any of:
    /home/mik/go_appengine/goroot/src/google.golang.org/api/googleapi (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mik/go-programs/src/google.golang.org/api/googleapi (from $GOPATH)
    /home/mik/goroot/pkg/src/google.golang.org/api/googleapi
    /home/mik/go_appengine/src/google.golang.org/api/googleapi
2015/03/14 23:13:37 Can't find package "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1" in any of:
    /home/mik/go_appengine/goroot/src/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/mik/go-programs/src/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1 (from $GOPATH)
    /home/mik/goroot/pkg/src/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1
    /home/mik/go_appengine/src/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1
2015/03/14 23:13:37 go-app-builder: build timing: 5×6g (223ms total), 0×gopack (0 total), 0×6l (0 total)
2015/03/14 23:13:37 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has change  thire repository and i missed it...

[google-api-go-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/)

So the solution is  to do go get to that  and evrthing working fine.

```
go get -u google.golang.org/api/storage/v1
```